# tcl expect scope

Tags: tcl, expect

The following setting under the `if` doesn't seem to take effect due to if block scoping:

```
 16 if {[string compare "$DEBUG" "ON"]!=0} {
 17     exp_internal 1
 18 }
 19 Rest of code that want the debug to be ON.
```

Is there a way to make the setting global as the rest of the code depends on it.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm puzzled by your logic: did you mean to say if debug `==` ON then turn on verbosity?

Comment: Try using the `eq` operator or `string equals` command for more clarity…

Comment: As written, the logic seems reversed, you will be turning on Expect's diagnostics when $DEBUG is not "ON". Try
`if {$DEBUG eq "ON"} { ...etc...`
If this doesn't work, try putting the line `puts "DEBUG=$DEBUG"` aheadd of this to check that DEBUG has the value you think it has.

Answer (score 2):

```
if { "$DEBUG" == "ON" } {
    exp_internal 1
}
```

Dealing the global settings you may want to pass `-d` option to the expect binary. According to manpage:

> This flag has the same effect as "exp_internal 1" at the beginning of an Expect script, plus the version of Expect is printed